# In Picasso library how can I now when my image gets loaded which event listener gets triggered?

Tags: android, picasso

Hello all I am using picasso in an android project now my question is that I need to show something on the image the picasso is loading that's why I want to know how am I able to know when picasso has loaded the image because only then I can add text on that image. Also if this functionality is not provided by picasso then is there any other way of doing this with picassso in android

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://192.168.0.15:1337/offers/" + image_url.get(position)).resize(350, 100).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
```

Now where to set text on the image here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include a callback argument into the request. Do whatever you want to do on image loading success or error response.

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: sorry at that time it was showing cannot accept answer within 7 mins anways thanx again